# Infinite series for recurrence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

**Question 1**

If I define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!} \tag 1$

(where $a_n$ are $3\times 3$ constant matrices indexed with n),

then can we re-write  $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!} \tag 2 $ and  $\sum_{n \ge 2} a_{n-2} \frac{z^n}{n!} \tag 3 $   in terms of A(z)?

**Question 2**

Can we write $\psi(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} na_{n}  z^n  \tag 4 $

in terms of any any existing infinite series such that we can also re write

$\sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n-1}  z^n    \tag 5 $ and  $\sum_{n \ge 2} a_{n-2}  z^n    \tag 6 $   in terms of $\psi(z)$?

NB :: Thease all are part of my attempts to solve $na_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ without using ODE. Means by using power series or any other infinte series

Answer (score 1):

1. The nine entries in your matrix are independent, so it is slightly simpler to think of nine separate equations.
2. Differentiate the first equation (2).  Then let $m=n-1$ and relabel the result.  Unfortunately, this turns it into a differential equation.
3. Let $\xi(z)$ be equation (3).  Then $\xi^{\prime}(z)$ can be rearranged in terms of $\psi(z)$.

$B(z)=\sum_{n\geq1}a_{n-1}{z^n\over n!}\\B\,^{\prime}(z)=\sum_{n\geq1}a_{n-1}{z^{n-1}\over (n-1)!}=\sum_{m\geq0}a_m{z^m\over m!}=B(z)$

Comment: Would please elaborate  .. My ultimate aim is to get the solution of that recurrence I mentioned. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Shall we plug the above nice properties in to $na_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ so that we can make an equation out of it..Is there any other alternative such that we can avoid ODE..Something sort of subtitution? I can make the give recurrence to $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{n-1}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{n-2}$ by substitution. But it doesnt make any difference..getting rid of that variable coeffienct is  really tough..any ideas?